# AdMob add ad unit does not work

Tags: android, ionic-framework, admob, ionic3

It's my first time using AdMob.  When I hit ADD AD UNIT button. It's constantly just loading and does not proceed to the next page. Any of you know what's happening? My app isn't published to the Playstore yet.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) ! Please read  [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) !

Comment: Check your internet connection, may be your internet speed is slow.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by disabling AdBlock on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Just disable all the extensions from your browser and try reloading that page or by logging out and then logging in and you'll get the access to ad units.